# Angular Bootstrap UI Popover does not appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've bumped my head into this now for 30mins and cannot find what I'm doing wrong:
I am including all needed modules (and others) in *index.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-scroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angularGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-count-to.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/srfrnk/re-tree/master/re-tree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector/master/ng-device-detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.9.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

I tell it to use the bootstrap ui module in *app.js*

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ng', 'ngRoute','angularFileUpload', 'duScroll', 'angularGrid', 'countTo', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ng.deviceDetector']);
```

and I am trying to add it inside an ng-repeat like this:

```
      <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
```

what's wrong??

Comment: How about the css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this............without uib

```
<button popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
```

Comment: `uib-popover` is as per docs - any specific reason why you think this will not work?

Comment: I was facing the same problem when i came across this example `http://plnkr.co/edit/4QQTNp7xrNKtkmBz4KdK?p=preview`.  In this example the popovers are not working with uib.

Comment: surprisingly this worked even though I thought I had tried it before (probably some typo then). So next step: how to make the popover appear also for disabled buttons

Comment: Popovers for .disabled or disabled elements must be triggered on a wrapper element. Like here I have wrapped disabled button with a <div> element and applied popover on it.

`<div popover="Safe text" popover-trigger="mouseenter"><button class="btn btn-default" disabled>just text</button></div>`